# jQuery Quick Edit problem

Tags: jquery

i use this 
http://www.mudaimemo.com/p/quickedit/#
and it work good
the problem is
i want use this is renaming some rows
like this

```
my name ok!! (edit | delete| rename)
```

now this will be too many like that

```
1my name ok!! (edit | delete| rename)
2my name ok!! (edit | delete| rename)
3my name ok!! (edit | delete| rename)
4my name ok!! (edit | delete| rename)
5my name ok!! (edit | delete| rename)
6my name ok!! (edit | delete| rename)
```

and if i make each one like that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // formnotifier
  $('#1').quickEdit();
  $('#2').quickEdit();
  $('#3').quickEdit();
  $('#4').quickEdit();
  $('#5').quickEdit();
  $('#6').quickEdit();   
});
```

is there any way to make it like that

```
$('#rename').find().prev(".a").quickEdit();
```

i dont understand
can any one make it for me
the job is
make it auto edit without repeat it

Comment: wrap them in a div and do a foreach of that div

Comment: i dont have html yet can you make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at their examples they have in HTML

```
<span id="demoText1">This is a jQuery Quick Edit Demo1.</span>
<a href="/quickedit.php" id="demo1" rel="demoText1">edit this text.</a>
```

and they execute the javascript

```
$('#demo1').quickEdit();
```

To do this with multiple elements you just have to add a class to all `a` elements and use that as the jquery selector ...
HTML

```
<span id="demoText1">This is a jQuery Quick Edit Demo1.</span>
<a href="/quickedit.php" class="quickedit" rel="demoText1">edit this text.</a>
<span id="demoText2">This is a jQuery Quick Edit Demo2.</span>
<a href="/quickedit.php" class="quickedit" rel="demoText2">edit this text.</a>
<span id="demoText3">This is a jQuery Quick Edit Demo3.</span>
<a href="/quickedit.php" class="quickedit" rel="demoText3">edit this text.</a>
```

Javascript

```
$('.quickedit').quickEdit();
```

Answer (score 1):

by your example, I guess you are allowed to :

```
$('#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6').quickEdit();
```